# RegEx multiline back reference

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to parse a text about genealogy. Every important person is referenced by a number located at beginning of line and is found with this regex:

```
/¦(\d+)/g
```

Let's ignore the name and other info for the moment. I'm trying to build a family tree. His children are listed underneath on different lines. They would be found with this regex:

```
/(\d+)\.\s[ivx]+\./g
```

Some children are unimportant and they don't have a reference number, only a roman id.

Here's a text extract (in french):

```
¦1873. Nicolas Chesne. Il s’est marié avec Catherine DeLavigne (1874). 
   Nicolas Chesne et Catherine DeLavigne ont eu un garçon :
1130.   i.  Bertrand Chenay. Il a été baptisé le 20 février 1622 à Yffiniac, St-Brieuc, Bretagne, France. Il s’est marié le 7 août 1656 à Québec, QC avec Marie Madeleine Belanger (1131), fille de Francois Belanger (1875) et de Marie Marthe Andree Guyon (1876). Marie Madeleine est décédée avant le 21 janvier 1671 à QC. Bertrand a été marchand. Il est décédé le 16 janvier 1683 à Québec, QC. Il a été inhumé le lendemain au même endroit. 

¦1875. Francois Belanger, fils de Francois Belanger (2724) et de Francoise Horlays (2725). Il est né vers 1616 à Lisieux, Normandie, France. Il s’est marié le 12 juillet 1637, vers l’âge de 20 ou 21 ans à Notre-Dame, Québec, QC avec Marie Marthe Andree Guyon (1876), âgée de treize ans, fille de Jean Guyon (1993) et de Marie Mathurine Madeleine Robin-Boule (1994). Francois est décédé vers avril 1687, vers l’âge de 70 ou 71 ans à Montmorency, QC. 
¦1876. Marie Marthe Andree Guyon. Elle est née le 12 mars 1624 à St-Jean-d’Angely, Saintes, Saintonge, France et a été baptisée le 18 mars 1624 au même endroit. Elle est décédée le 29 août 1696, à l’âge de 72 ans au Cap St-Ignace, Montmagny, QC. Elle a été inhumée le 1er octobre 1696 au même endroit. 
   Francois Belanger et Marie Marthe Andree Guyon ont eu treize enfants (six garçons et sept filles) :
    i.  Nicolas Belanger. Il est né vers 1633 à St-Thomas de Touques, Lisieux, Normandie, France. Il s’est marié le 11 janvier 1660, vers l’âge de 26 ou 27 ans à Québec, QC avec Marie Rainville, âgée d’environ 19 ou 20 ans, fille de Paul de Rainville (2513) et de Rolline Pauline Poete (2514). Marie est née vers 1640 à St-Thomas de Touques, Lisieux, Normandie, France. Elle est décédée le 6 novembre 1711, vers l’âge de 70 ou 71 ans à Beauport, Québec, QC. Nicolas est décédé le 19 octobre 1682, vers l’âge de 48 ou 49 ans à Beauport, Québec, QC. Il a été inhumé le lendemain au même endroit. 
2802.   ii. Charles Belanger (ancêtre de Pollus par Diane). Il a été baptisé le 19 août 1640 à Québec, QC. Il s’est marié le 21 novembre 1663 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Barbe Delphine Cloutier (2803), fille de Zacharie Cloutier (1495) et de Marie Madeleine Aymard (1496). Barbe Delphine est décédée le 24 avril 1711 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Charles est décédé le 14 décembre 1692 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Il a été inhumé le lendemain au même endroit. 
1131.   iii.    Marie Madeleine Belanger (ancêtre de Pollus par Diane). Elle a été baptisée le 15 février 1643 à Québec, QC. Elle s’est mariée le 7 août 1656 à Québec, QC avec Bertrand Chenay (1130), fils de Nicolas Chesne (1873) et de Catherine DeLavigne (1874). Bertrand est décédé le 16 janvier 1683 à Québec, QC. Marie Madeleine est décédée avant le 21 janvier 1671 à QC. 
    iv. Marguerite Belanger. Elle a été baptisée le 23 novembre 1645 à Notre-Dame, Québec, QC. Elle s’est mariée le 19 novembre 1663 à Notre-Dame-de-la-Visitation, Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Antoine Berson, âgé d’environ 22 ou 23 ans. Il est né vers 1640 à St-Jacques-de-la-Boucherie, Paris, Ile-de-France, France. Il est décédé avant le 4 juillet 1665, avant l’âge de 25 ans à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Plus tard, Marguerite s’est remariée le 13 décembre 1666 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Louis Levasseur, âgé d’environ 29 ou 30 ans. Il est né vers 1636 à St-Jacques, Paris, Île de France, France. Marguerite a été inhumée le 22 janvier 1703 à Notre-Dame, Québec, QC. 
    v.  Jean Francois Belanger. Il a été baptisé le 15 février 1648 à Québec, QC. Il s’est marié le 17 novembre 1671 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Marie Cloutier, âgée de seize ans, fille de Jean Cloutier (1155) et de Marie Martin (1156). Marie est née le 16 février 1655. Elle est décédée le 22 avril 1713, à l’âge de 58 ans à L’Islet-sur-mer, L’Islet, QC. Jean Francois a été capitaine de Milice de la Seigneurie de Bonsecours. Il est décédé le 5 février 1682 au Cap St-Ignace, Montmagny, QC. Il a été inhumé le lendemain au même endroit. 
2421.   vi. Marie Charlotte Francoise Belanger (ancêtre de Pollus par Joseph Albert André). Elle a été baptisée le 30 juin 1650 à Québec, QC. Elle s’est mariée le 19 octobre 1665 à La-Visitation-de-Notre-Dame, Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Jean Langlois (ancêtre de Pollus par Joseph Albert André) (2420), fils de Noel Langlois (2601) et de Francoise Grenier-Garnier (2602). Jean est décédé le 25 août 1687. Ultérieurement, Marie Charlotte Francoise s’est remariée le 4 juillet 1691 à St-Pierre, Île d’Orléans, Montmorency, QC avec Thomas Rousseau, âgé d’environ 59 ou 60 ans. Il est né vers 1631 à Oroux, Poitiers, Poitou, France. Marie Charlotte Francoise a été inhumée le 3 octobre 1710 à Québec, QC. 
    vii.    Mathurine Belanger. Elle est née le 11 juin 1652 à Québec, QC et a été baptisée le 28 octobre 1652 au même endroit. Elle s’est mariée le 18 septembre 1673, à l’âge de vingt et un ans à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Jean Maheu, fils de Jacques Maheu et d’Anne Convent (3223). Jean est décédé avant le 30 septembre 1674 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Par la suite, Mathurine s’est remariée le 2 octobre 1674, à l’âge de vingt-deux ans à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Antoine Deserre, âgé d’environ 35 ou 36 ans. Il est né vers 1638 à St-Amand-de-Boixe, Angoulême, Angoumais, France. Ensuite, Mathurine s’est remariée le 26 avril 1688, à l’âge de 35 ans à Neuville, Portneuf, QC avec Francois Gregoire, âgé d’environ 22 ou 23 ans. Il est né vers 1665 à Ste-Anne, Montpellier, Languedoc, France. Mathurine a été inhumée le 18 janvier 1698 à Neuville, Portneuf, QC. 
    viii.   Louis Belanger. Il est né le 18 décembre 1654 à Québec, QC et a été baptisé le 9 janvier 1655 au même endroit. Il s’est marié le 3 novembre 1682, à l’âge de vingt-sept ans à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Marguerite Lefrancois, âgée de dix-sept ans, fille de Charles Lefrancois (1607) et de Marie Madeleine Triot (1608). Marguerite est née le 2 février 1665 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Elle est décédée le 29 octobre 1735, à l’âge de 70 ans. Louis a été inhumé le 1er octobre 1724 à L’Islet-sur-mer, L’Islet, QC. 
    ix. Louise Belanger. Elle est née vers 1657 à QC. Elle s’est mariée le 14 novembre 1679, vers l’âge de 21 ou 22 ans à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC avec Jean Cloutier, âgé de vingt-sept ans, fils de Jean Cloutier (1155) et de Marie Martin (1156). Jean est né le 20 février 1652 à Québec, QC. Il est décédé le 4 décembre 1709, à l’âge de 57 ans à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Louise a été inhumée le 5 juillet 1726 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. 
    x.  Genevieve Belanger. Elle est née vers 1659. Elle s’est mariée le 23 novembre 1682, vers l’âge de 22 ou 23 ans au Cap St-Ignace, Montmagny, QC avec Guillaume Frete, âgé d’environ 34 ou 35 ans. Il est né vers 1647 à Meaux, Brie, France. 
    xi. Guillaume Belanger. Il est né le 31 mars 1661 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC et a été baptisé le 4 avril 1661 au même endroit. Il est décédé en août 1661, à l’âge de 4 ou 5 mois à QC. 
    xii.    Jacques Belanger. Il est né le 24 juillet 1662 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC et a été baptisé le 30 juillet 1662 à La-Visitation-de-Notre-Dame, Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC. Il s’est marié le 22 novembre 1691, à l’âge de vingt-neuf ans au Cap St-Ignace, Montmagny, QC avec Marie Elisabeth Thibault, âgée de dix-huit ans. Elle est née le 16 mars 1673 à Ste-Anne-de-Beaupré, Montmorency, QC. Elle est décédée le 12 juin 1756, à l’âge de 83 ans. Jacques a été inhumé le 17 août 1699 à Notre-Dame-de-Bon-Secours, L’Islet-sur-Mer, L’Islet, QC. 
    xiii.   Anne Belanger. Elle est née le 26 juillet 1664 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC et a été baptisée le lendemain au même endroit. Elle a été inhumée le 24 août 1665 à Château-Richer, Montmorency, QC.
```

I'm trying to create a table (ID, ParentID) using Notepad++ RegEx engine (I guess I need to use another engine that support lookbehind). But I am juggling with trying to reference a group from another line and I can't get it to work. Since the references are on different lines, I figured this would call for a global flag but not a multiline flag. In javascript I would have:

```
/(\d+)\.\s[ivx]+\./g
```

But I'm pretty sure that I need to make a positive lookbehind which is not supported by JavaScript nor Notepad++. Here's the way I see the resolution of this problem: First, I find the child ID reference using `(\d+)\.\s[ivx]+\.` then I search for the parent ID using a lookbehind `(?<=¦(\d+))`

Any help would be appreciated.

Substitution output should be for this extract:

```
1130, 1873
2802, 1876
1131, 1876
2421, 1876
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a scripting language like Perl or Python? It seems you got your regex down, but I'd say doing it in Notepad++ is a bit restrictive. And how do you differentiate between children and grandchildren (or is it a problem at all?)

Comment: The document has references for these. In english, it would look like 123. John Doe. is the son of Hercules(124) and Athena (125) And Notepad++ is not really the problem.

Comment: Can you at least include that information in the line `ii. Michel Frenette (ancêtre de ...`. It seems to be an important piece of information.

Comment: 728. ii. Michel Frenette (ancêtre de Pollus par Diane). Il est né le 23 avril 1692 à Neuville, Portneuf, QC et a été baptisé le même jour au même endroit. Il s’est marié le 20 août 1714, à l’âge de vingt-deux ans à Ste-Anne-de-la-Pérade, Champlain, QC avec Marie Josephe Richer-Lafleche (729), fille de Pierre Richer (869) et de Marie Dorothee Brassard (870). Marie Josephe est décédée le 8 novembre 1758. Michel est décédé le 19 août 1771, à l’âge de 79 ans. Il a été inhumé le lendemain à Ste-Famille, Cap Santé, Portneuf, QC.

Comment: This text really references the spouse "Marie Josephe Richer-Lafleche (729)" and her parents "fille de Pierre Richer (869) et de Marie Dorothee Brassard (870)" I don't have any references to his parents.

Comment: The result for this example would be: 728, 1276

Comment: What is your input-output?

Comment: I changed the INPUT to have a ¦ before the ID because I beleive that I need to have a lookbehind.